# Conditionally replacing blank values in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, missing-data

I have a dataframe which has a sparsely populated column.  Most of the values are blank; the only other values are 'Buy' and 'Sell.'  I would like to replace the blank values with 'long' if the last non-blank value was 'Buy' or 'short' if the last non-blank value was 'Sell.'  I can do this easily enough in a loop but am wondering if there is a non-loopy way of accomplishing this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) or [`combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html) for replace `None`s created by helper `df` with [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) and `ffill` ([`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) with method `ffill` - forward filling `NaN`s and `None`s):

```
np.random.seed(12)
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':np.random.choice(['Buy','Sell', None], 10, p=(.2,.2,.6)),
                   'B':np.random.choice(['Buy','Sell', None], 10, p=(.2,.2,.6)),
                   'C':np.random.choice(['Buy','Sell', None], 10, p=(.2,.2,.6))})

print (df)

      A     B     C
0   Buy  Sell  None
1  None  None   Buy
2  Sell  None   Buy
3  None  None   Buy
4   Buy   Buy  Sell
5  None  None  None
6  None  None  None
7   Buy  None  None
8  None  None  Sell
9   Buy   Buy  None

df = df.fillna(df.replace({'Sell':'short', 'Buy':'long'}).ffill())
#alternative solution
#df = df.combine_first(df.replace({'Sell':'short', 'Buy':'long'}).ffill())
print (df)
       A      B      C
0    Buy   Sell   None
1   long  short    Buy
2   Sell  short    Buy
3  short  short    Buy
4    Buy    Buy   Sell
5   long   long  short
6   long   long  short
7    Buy   long  short
8   long   long   Sell
9    Buy    Buy  short
```

Explanation:

```
print (df.replace({'Sell':'short', 'Buy':'long'}))
       A      B      C
0   long  short   None
1   None   None   long
2  short   None   long
3   None   None   long
4   long   long  short
5   None   None   None
6   None   None   None
7   long   None   None
8   None   None  short
9   long   long   None

print (df.replace({'Sell':'short', 'Buy':'long'}).ffill())
       A      B      C
0   long  short   None
1   long  short   long
2  short  short   long
3  short  short   long
4   long   long  short
5   long   long  short
6   long   long  short
7   long   long  short
8   long   long  short
9   long   long  short
```

Comment: Thanks. The first block of your answer seems to do exactly what I'm looking for with Buys and Sells preserved and blanks replaced by longs and shorts  In your explanation (block 2), though, the results consist entirely of longs and shorts--the original Buys and Sells are gone.  Looking at your code, the latter is what I would have expected.  Trying your code, however, I get the former--which is what I wanted. It looks like I'm replacing the Buys with long and the Sells with short an then doing a forward fill.  But why are the original Buys and Sells retained?

Comment: Because I use `df.fillna` by second `df` created by `replace` and `ffill`. So it replace original `Nones` by values in second `df.` Similar working `combine_first`.